# Arguments Authorization in Graphql Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, graphql

In Graphql-Ruby docs, there is way to implement the Authorization such as visibility or accessibility in the arguments field, but i didn't understand clearly to implement myself,How do i do that?

Answer (score 1):

I think the documentation here is pretty good on this: https://graphql-ruby.org/authorization/authorization.html

This is query time authorisation, e.g. allowing point in time authorization of a given set of arguments over the API, based on some other contextual information.

You talk about visibility, I guess you mean in a `schema` from an introspection point of view. The Gem doesn't provide a way to apply authorization logic to alter the view of the schema for different callers. I guess it would be possible but do you want to support code which has to resolve correctly against multiple schemas or sets of arguments?